# Rails 3.2 has_many :through how to get only models related in join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

Surely, This is a simple question but i cant complain

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :offers
   has_many :offices,:through=> :offers
   has_many :addresses,:through => :offices
   has_many :locations,:through => :adreesses,:include => :offices
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :service
   belongs_to :office
end

class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :offers
   has_many :services,:through => :offers
   has_one :adreess
end

class Address
   belongs_to :office
   belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :addressess
   has_many :offices,:through => :addresses,:uniq=>true
end
```

I want to display, for example:

```
Service name: Entrega especial

  Location name: Distrito Capital
     Offices:
         Name: San Martin

  Location name: Carabobo
     Offices:
         Name: San diego
```

But when I do this

```
service = Service.where(:nombre=> "Entrega especial")
locations = service.locations

locations.offices.each do |o|
   puts o.nombre # only I want the offices with that service
in that Location, no all offices in that location
end
```

I can't realize how to only display the offices in the relationship, rather than all offices in that Location even without that service offer, in a snoth way, without to use an assosiation extension, and manage proxy_xxx objects

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to reframe your question? I find it quite hard to understand what you actually want to know or achieve.

Comment: I Edit the part what I want to display, I wanna group offices per Location, but show only the offices who offer an specific service in this Location related

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's better to go through the offices association

```
@offices = service.offices.includes(:location)

@offices.group_by(&:location).each do |location, offices_by_location|
  puts "Location: #{location}"
  offices_by_location.each do |office|
    puts "Office: #{office}"
  end
end
```

Comment: uhmmm, ok, interesting, I gonna try this way, Thanks, I keep seeking other ways to do this